# Roslib with Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am trying to use roslibjs inside angular 10. I run the following commands to install roslib and it's type definition

```
npm i roslib
npm i @types/roslib --save-dev
```

I do the following in the component.ts file at the top of the file

```
import * as ROSLIB from 'roslib';

ros: any;
ex_publisher:any;
```

Inside the constructor I call this and it works

```
    this.ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
    });
```

But I don't know how to subscribe or publish to a topic

Normally I would do something similar to this but it doesn't know anything about publisher

```
      this.ex_publisher = new ROSLIB.Topic({
      ros : this.ros,
      name : 'test/testname',
      messageType : 'std_msgs/String'
    });

    this.ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
    });

    this.ros.on('connection', function() {
      console.log("connected to ROS");
      console.log("sending test message over ROS");      
      
      this.ex_publisher.data  = 'hello'; // error here doesn't know about data
      this.ex_publisher.publish(); // error here also
      
    });
```

What is the best way of bringing in the roslib script. Also if I want to share the ros connection among all components how should I set this up in Angular 10?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So here you ask two questions (and I will answer boths).

First question : how to use roslibjs ? And second question how to share a ressource (like the roslibjs connection) to multiple compoment in an angular application ? Let me answer to the the second question first :

### How to share a resource lkike the roslibjs connection between multiple Angular components ?

One of the fundamentals concept in angular is the concept of "Service" which is strongly coupled to the concept of Dependency Injection. So please read [this section](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) of the angular doc to understand.

But to explain what is a service, imagine that this is a Class that "Angular" will give to all componenents that will require them.

So for me the best solution is to create a ROSLibService that will be given to all components that need to interact with ROS. (I will show a sample later).

### How to use ROSLibJS in an Angular application ?

Installation :

Use the classic

```
npm -i roslib
npm -D @types/roslib
```

Then add roslib to the allowedCommonJsDependencies of the angular.json file.

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ....
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["roslib"]
          },
```

Here is an example of an angular service that I use to share ROSLib between my components.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as ROSLIB from 'roslib';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Here you define the type (as in your .msg, but in Typescript)
export interface String {
   data: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoslibService {
  private _ros: ROSLIB.Ros;
  private _connected = new Subject<boolean>();
  private _chat = new Subject<String>();

  private _topic?: ROSLIB.Topic;

  constructor() {
    this._connected.next(false);

    this._ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({});
    this._ros.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:9090');
    this._ros.on('connection', (event: any) => {
      this._connected.next(true);
      this.subscribeToTopics();
    })
    // TODO : Manage the events "disconnect" and "error".
  }

  get connected(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this._connected.asObservable();
  }

  get chat(): Observable<String>{
    return this._chat.asObservable();
  }    

  private subscribeToTopics(){
    this._topic = new ROSLIB.Topic({ros: this._ros, name: '/chat', messageType: 'std_msgs/String'});
    this._topic.subscribe((msg: String)=>{ this._chat.next(msg);});        
  }
}
```

It is very important to create your topic when the connection is established (because subscription is perfomed in the topic's constructor by the roslibjs).

Then, you can write a simple angular component that display your "/chat" topic like this :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { String, RoslibService } from './roslib.service';
    
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <h1>Roslib JS tester</h1>
        <p>Connected : {{this.connected}}</p>
        <p>Message : {{this.message}}</p>`,
      styleUrls: [''],
    })
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'ng-roslib';
    
    connected = false;
    message = '';
    
    constructor(private roslibService: RoslibService) {
        this.roslibService.chat.subscribe((msg: String)=>{
          this.message = msg.data;
        });
        this.roslibService.connected.subscribe((connected: boolean)=>{
          this.connected = connected;
        });
    } 
}
```

Be carefull : Angular 12 use Webpack 5, and there is an incompatibilty between roslibjs and webpack5. See [this issue](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/issues/382) to understand.